# Delayed response while using XMLSocket

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, sockets, flash-builder

I am trying to interact flash AS3 file with a C# based socket server. Server is designed to give two response at a given time, there can be varied delay between first and second response. However what I find is the second response arrives along with next response.

```
var xmlsock:XMLSocket = new XMLSocket();
xmlsock.connect("127.0.0.1", 9231);

xmlsock.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onDataHandler);

function onDataHandler(event:DataEvent):void {
    trace("[" + event.type + "] " + event.data);
}
```

When I check the output using trace I find below I have separated each response with dashed line. Response test and test2 should have been come in for a single request, however they come in two different response.

Current result

```
[data] 
[data] test
--------------------------------------------------
[data] test2
[data] test
--------------------------------------------------
[data] test2
[data] test
--------------------------------------------------
[data] test2
[data] test
--------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the result what I was expecting
    Expected result

```
[data] test
[data] test2
--------------------------------------------------
[data] test
[data] test2
--------------------------------------------------
[data] test
[data] test2
--------------------------------------------------
```

Any insight in understanding XMLSocket and resolving the issue would be great.

Comment: What about server code? Didn't it send something incorrect like an empty message at a conversation start?

Comment: Why is receiving the results in the "wrong" order causing you a problem? Your Async code should not be expecting a specific order. Post some of your async code + more specifics on why this is an issue.

Comment: When you say "server is designed to give two responses at a time", is this some sort of output buffering that the server is doing (it waits for the buffer to fill, then sends out the data), or just that you expect two responses for every request? Also, in your diagram, what is that first empty response from the server? Finally, the code for the Flash side is so simple, I can't see how that is causing anything to go wrong, I'd look at your server. Try connecting to the socket with telnet: `telnet servername_or_ip server_port`, or some other client and see how it behaves.

Comment: @maxkar server sends bunch of status codes initially i.e. first response. Server works fine, I have verified by connecting the server to telnet.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship server acts as interface between hardware controls and flash. Hardware button have two states one "on" state and another "off" state, time gap between the hardware button going from "on" state to "off" state determines two behaviors (long press and short press). As the off state trigger doesn't arrive in time, flash behaves as if the button was in on state for long time. So the delay in flash responding is certainly making the flash application fail.

Comment: @Sunil first empty response is what flash display, I don't see that in telnet. Unfortunately server code is developed by client's team and code access is difficult.

Comment: Is it possible that your server is not terminating one of the responses  with a "zero" byte as described in the [docs for XMLSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html)? That would be one reason why Flash would behave this way. Perhaps you can use a packet sniffing tool to see what the server is sending (not sure if you could determine that w/telnet).

Comment: Thanks Sunil!! I will check for the "zero" byte, possibly can be the reason. Could you suggest some sniffing tool... kinda new to this side?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. When I've done similar tasks, the socket was sending system state, and hardware actions were mapped to appear to be mouse events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Socket class to get this working. Thanks all for the help...

```
var socket:Socket = new Socket("localhost", 2553);

socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, socketConnectHandler, false, 0, true);
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler, false, 0, true);

function socketConnectHandler(event:Event):void{
    trace("Connection has been established ");
}

function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void{   

    var stream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    socket.writeBytes(stream, 0, 0);

    var data:String = "";

    while(socket.bytesAvailable){
        data += socket.readUTFBytes(1);
    }   

    trace("data "+ data);   
}
```